# Sign out spreadsheet after inactivity

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I would like to implement a "time out" on my spreadsheets when there is inactivity. 
User often forget accounts open and there is sensitive information I don't like to leave open.

Any ideas how I can do this with a JavaScript?

Comment: IMHO you should avoid using JavaScript tag for questions that are really specific to Google Apps Script, you'll get inappropriate answers sometimes. I understand why you did it but I notice quite often that answers reflect absence of knowledge of Google Apps Script. I'm afraid it is the case below. That said, I think what you ask is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this with google apps script.
The only way is to write a browser extension (chrome extension etc).
The fact that you dont know jquery (not required for this though) probably implies you might not have enough experience to do this.